# Execute a command as another user by providing THEIR password

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, execute-command, su

I need to execute a command as another user by providing THEIR password. This must be able to be done without a terminal aka purely through bash script. I also need to be able to do this without installing a custom package (*sshpass*, etc) or configuring any root-accessible files (*sudoers*, etc).

Things I have tried:

1. `sudo -u 'myuser' -- sh -c 'mycommand'`
2. `su - 'myuser' -c 'mycommand'`
3. `ssh 'myuser'@localhost 'mycommand'`

All of these work in accomplishing the goal of executing a command as another user. However, the authentication is the problem...

1. `sudo` - Allows you to supply password through standard input using the `-S` flag. However, it requests **your** password - not the password of the user you're trying to execute the command as.
2. `su` - Allows you to supply **their** password instead of yours but it can only be supplied through a terminal!
3. `ssh` - Allows you to supply **their** password but it also can only be supplied through a terminal. It also has much more overhead than the previous two.

If `su` had a `-S` flag like `sudo` this problem would be solved.
Does something (built-in) exist that can perform this operation? If not, why doesn't it exist? There doesn't seem to be any issue with security because `sudo` already provides the ability to pass passwords through standard input.

Comment: `sudoers` has the `targetpw` option, but you don't want it for some reason. As for: "If not, why doesn't it exist?" Why should it, especially if a default command can be configured for this, and installable packages can provide equivalent functionality?

Comment: I want my code to work out of the box without having to have root access to configure the sudoers file.

Comment: We all want a lot of things. Why don't you file a feature request for `su`, and see what the devs say about it?